# Using schema.org or RDFa microformatting with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, schema, microformats, rdfa

Wordpress tends to strip out all kinds of code in VISUAL mode, including microformatting. The current WP (3.2.1) seems beyond compatibility with earlier widgets, including wp-RDFa (which I thought showed promise). As discussed in [this Google group post]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/schemaorg-discussion/E72kDkuguk4/discussion, clients often need to use VISUAL, thus the problem in using any kind of microformatting with Wordpress. Yet we want to start using microformats of some kind. (Damn you wordpress!)

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Still early days for this plugin, but give it a try...

http://schemaforwordpress.com/